# My array (myLeads) elements are not rendered in HTML list but they are showing correctly in console. I want to print myLeads[ ] elements in HTML list

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

```js
let myLeads = [];
const inputEl = document.getElementById("input-el");
const inputBtn = document.getElementById("input-btn");
const ulEl = document.getElementById("ul-el");

inputBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    myLeads.push(inputEl.value);
    console.log(myLeads)
})

let arr = [2, 3, "fadf"]

/*arr[] elements are rendered correctly in HTML list. But myLeads[] elements are not rendered in HTML list, as they are printed correctly in console.*/

for(let i = 0; i < myLeads.length; i++){
    ulEl.innerHTML += "<li>" + myLeads[i] + "</li>"
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=\, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>save leads</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="input-el">
    <button id="input-btn">Save tabs</button>
    <ul id="ul-el"></ul>
    <script src="/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not updating the HTML element anywhere when the click event is being fired. That means your list is only populated by the initial elements of `myLeads` when the page is refreshed and then never again.

Move the cycle for generating `li` elements into a function, for example

```
function updateList(arr){
    ulEl.innerHTML = "";
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        ulEl.innerHTML += "<li>" + myLeads[i] + "</li>"
    }
}
```

and then call it inside the event handler

```
inputBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    myLeads.push(inputEl.value);
    console.log(myLeads)
    updateList(myLeads);
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Put the loop in a function and call it. Also make sure to reset the ul to be empty

```js
let myLeads = [];
const inputEl = document.getElementById("input-el");
const inputBtn = document.getElementById("input-btn");
const ulEl = document.getElementById("ul-el");

inputBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    myLeads.push(inputEl.value);
    updateList();
})

let arr = [2, 3, "fadf"]

/*arr[] elements are rendered correctly in HTML list. But myLeads[] elements are not rendered in HTML list, as they are printed correctly in console.*/
function updateList(){
    ulEl.innerHTML = "";
    for(let i = 0; i < myLeads.length; i++){
        ulEl.innerHTML += "<li>" + myLeads[i] + "</li>"
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=\, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>save leads</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="input-el">
    <button id="input-btn">Save tabs</button>
    <ul id="ul-el"></ul>
    <script src="/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works in function call but myLeads is printed many times as function is invoked.

Comment: Why it is not working outside function?

Comment: @bug_29 it was working but `myLeads` is empty initially, so the loop executes once and is done, it doesn't watch for changes to `myLeads`

Comment: @dokokos make sure you empty the `ulEl` see my example